# Why is $ split valid syntax?

Tags: perl, syntax, declaration

There's already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745278/is-space-supposed-to-be-ignored-between-a-sigil-and-its-variable-name) for why `my %     foo;` or `my $           string;` both compile in perl, but I was surprised to see that this is also the case when the variable name is itself a function, such as [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $ split = 'why does this work?';

say $split;
# why does this work?
```

How can this be the case?

Comment: Same reason that `$split` works. Being preceded by a sigil is significant, being immediately preceded by one is not. The whitespace is irrelevant there.

Comment: If you want to know the nitty-gritty details, it all happens in [toke.c](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.24.0/toke.c), perl's lexer. In `perl -e'$ split'`, when the lexer encounters `$`, it checks for a bunch of different things like `$#`; if none of those things match, it says that the next token must be an identifier, so `split` is treated as an identifier, not a keyword. In `perl -e 'split'`, when the lexer encounters `s`, it does a keyword lookup and finds a match, so `split` is treated as a keyword. See lines 5293 and 6225 in the version of toke.c that I linked.